# Android source code for locationmanager only?

Tags: android, location, currentlocation

I want to know how Geo Location is found through a Network provider without GPS in an Android application?

- How exactly is triangulation of cell towers implemented in code and how is latitude and longitude of the cell towers is obtained to get the accurate location through `NETWORK_PROVIDER`?
- Where exactly can I find the source code which implements this functionality? (Android is a huge codebase and I don't know my way around it).
- I cannot use the `LocationManager` or `LocationProvider` or any class or objects directly as I want to mimic this functionality in hardware so I just want to convert the source code to C with same functionality.

Comment: in this link you can find it..http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/location/LocationManager.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to say, but Google has not open-sourced this part of the code.

You can see LocationManagerService - it [talks to a remote service](http://androidxref.com/4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/LocationManagerService.java) using a LocationProviderProxy. The implementation is in a NetworkLocation.apk in pre KitKat distributions and shipped by Google on every Android phone. (In KitKat it is in Google Play)

Relevant package name for KitKat :

```
private static final String NETWORK_LOCATION_SERVICE_ACTION =
        "com.android.location.service.v3.NetworkLocationProvider";
```

---

Google uses WiFi positioning data + Cell ID information for triangulation.

I think you want to know how cell ID position occurs - there are many positioning protocols that have evolved from 2G to WCDMA to LTE. I think you will find this Spirent white paper interesting - [An overview of Hybrid Location technologies](http://www.spirent.com/White-Papers/Mobile/Hybrid_Location_Technologies_Overview_WhitePaper)